# Undefined index variable PHP

Tags: php, get, indexing, undefined

Okay, so this seems to be very common, but none of the things ive read has helped me, so is there anyone who knows why my variables seems to be unset..

EDIT: sorry forgot the place out the error, Its on line 169, which is:

```
if($world['$queryi'] != 0)

<?php

  if(isset($_GET['upgrade']))
  {
  if($_GET['upgrade'] > 0 && $_GET['upgrade'] < 15){ 

  $_GET['upgrade'];
  $id = $_GET['upgrade'];
  $queryi = "column_$id"; // This shows as undefined.
  $querye = "column_name_$id"; // This shows as undefined

  //When printing them out alone, they are defined, with the value i need them to be.

  if($id>=1 && $id <=14)
  {
//$world[] <- array from outside of the $_GET area (ive tried having it inside, same error)

   if($world['$queryi'] != 0)
   {

   }
   else
   {

       echo "query turned out zero";
   }

  }
  else
  {
      echo "something went wrong.";
  }
 }
 }

?>

//EDIT this is the arrayQUery which seems to be causing the problem..
$query = "SELECT * from this WHERE userid='".$user['id']."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$world=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Does anyome have a clue, whats wrong?

Comment: its mean your variable is not set, can you write complete error , you are getting

Comment: So you've not specified which is your error - and suggesting us to find your error by ourselves? No thank you.

Comment: why is $_GET['upgrade']; on its own line?

Comment: What variable is undefined?  What is the error that you get?

Comment: No the error is undefined index on line 169 
WHich is:
    if($world['$queryi'] != 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you comment I found following problem with your code

Why did you write $queryi in single quote in this line `if($world['$queryi'] != 0)`. As single quote means string not veritable. So your code means, search for index '$queryi'. But what you want to do is, you want to search for this string index => `"column_name_$id"`. So, Either remove single quotes or change it to double quote.

so correct code will be

`if($world[$queryi] != 0)`

Comment: Yes, ure right, that was right in front of me all the time, finally! I should have tried that earlier, that did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: It always happens with us, sometime we ignore the small mistakes... :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$_GET['upgrade'];
$id = $_GET['upgrade'];
$queryi = "column_$id"; // This shows as undefined.
$querye = "column_name_$id"; // This shows as undefined
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['upgrade'])) { 
    $id = $_GET['upgrade'];
} else {
    $id = 1;
}

$queryi = "column_" . $id; // This shows as undefined.
$querye = "column_name_" . $id; // This shows as undefined
```

Should do the trick.

Also this line needs to be checked if it's set or not.. I think this causes the error ..:

```
if($world['$queryi'] != 0)
```

change it to:

```
if(isset($world[$queryi]) && $world[$queryi] != 0)
```

Comment: No ive tried that aswell, the error appears at this line:

if($world['$queryi'] != 0)

Comment: Also added a check if GET upgrade isset or not

Comment: @user2866639 Where do you set the $world variable?

Comment: No, still the same notice.. ive done this so many times before, and never encountered this problem, its just weird..

Comment: @user2866639 I think you need to show us the array and it's output. The undefined index is because of the array..

Comment: And the $world[] is working, it just seems when put together with the variable it stops working..